# regarding some stored proceedure

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I got 2 tables :-

**TableName - Ques**

```
QuesID|Ques|QuesAns|QuesTypeID|Active
```

**TableName - QuesType**

```
QuesTypeID|QuesType|Active
```

Now when I add a new question in my code, it first asks for QuesType then Ques and lastly Answer. What I want is that 
when new record is added in DB,QuesTypeID column in Ques table should be set according to the value QuesTypeID in QuesType TAble.
Like lets say the QuesType user selects was "general Ques" and this type "General Ques" has ths QuesTypeID as 1 in QuesType Table.
Now what i want is that when new record is selected the column QuesTypeID be set as 1 in the Ques Table. 
What changes do I need to make in the following SP ?

```
ALTER PROC [Admin].[sp_InsertUpdateQues]
(
        @QuesID bigint,
        @Ques nvarchar(1000)=null,
        @QuesAns nvarchar(2000)=null,
        @QuesTypeID bigint=null,
        @Active bit=null
)
AS
BEGIN

        END
END
```

Comment: This seems perfectly fine to what you have described. What is the problem?

Comment: Please don't prefix your stored procs with "sp_",they are meant for system stored procs like "sp_help".You are just adding additional overhead to SQL Server.Instead prefix them with "usp_"

Comment: @Astander :: I am confused. How is QuesTypeID getting set when new Ques is added ? I mean the user is given the Option to select QuesType on my page. Where is this QuesTypeID value coming from ?

Comment: @SriNivas :: I understand that. I am working with previously made Sps. I have not wrote these.

Comment: Have you had a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.dropdownlist.aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listitem.aspx ? Is this what you are using to give the user the options for Question Types?

Comment: @Astander :: Using Telerik's combobox actually

Comment: Don't prefix stored procedures at all. Theres no reason to.

Comment: And who defined the table with BIGINT? /facepalm If you're using a telerik combobox, then the values would be on the combobox, I don't understand what you mean by where QuesTypeID is coming from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading your question and comments I think you might be confused about the actual code calling the stored procedure.

1. The SP as written takes in a QuesTypeId, so there aren't any changes that need to be done to it and instead you need to make sure the calling code is aware of how to get a QuesTypeId from a QuesType.
2. Now this gets us to the Telerik ComboBox. Each ComboBox Item has two properties, text and value. These two properties can either have the same or different values. The text property is shown to the user and value property is what is sent to the database. Thus, you can set the text property to QuesType and value to QuesTypeId and this is how the QuesTypeId is set.

The following link from the the [Telerik documentation](http://www.telerik.com/help/winforms/combobox-and-listbox-%28obsolete%29-combobox-working-with-items-get-selected-item.html) page shows how you can get at both the text and value properties of the selected ComboBox item by using:

radMenuComboItem1.ComboBoxElement.SelectedText 
radMenuComboItem1.ComboBoxElement.SelectedValue